# How to recover EMR from "Terminated with errors Instance failure" Status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr

I am new to AWS EMR, several days ago I stopped(not terminated) the EMR EC2 instances and then the EMR cluster status become "Terminated with errors Instance failure", how to recover it? I cannot find the related EC2 instances anymore.

Comment: Did you get the answer?. am facing the same situation.

Comment: Were you using a spot instance cluster? You should be using On demand or Reserved to avoid this kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this unanswered question:

Refer link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-troubleshoot-failed.html

- Step 1: Gather data about the issue
- Step 2: Check the environment
- Step 3: Look at the last state change
- Step 4: Examine the log files
- Step 5: Test the cluster step by step

Possible issue:
the underlying hardware may not be available.

Possible solution:
Create a Clone of the errored cluster with same or different hardware config.